# Getting row_number for from jsonb_array_elements or jsonb_to_recordset

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, jsonb

I'm doing a cross join lateral on an jsonb array and I'm looking to get the row_number (or its equivalent) for the array elements. looking at the row_number docs I see that I'd need to do a "order by" in addition to the "partition by", but there's not really a sort criterion I could use -- arrays just have a set order, and I need to retrieve the index into the array along with the rest of the data.

The client table will have entries like this

```json
{
  "id": "cj49q33oa000",
  "email": {
    "address": "",
    "after": "2016-06-28T12:28:58.016Z",
    "error": "Et corporis sed."
  },
  "name": "Arnold Schinner",
  "birthdate": "2016-07-29T05:09:33.693Z",
  "status": "paused",
  "sex": "f",
  "waist": [
    {
      "completed": "2017-06-23T10:37:37.500Z"
    },
    {
      "planned": "2017-06-23T10:37:37.500Z"
    },
    {
      "planned": "2017-06-23T10:37:37.500Z"
    },
    {
      "planned": "2017-06-23T10:37:37.500Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

and I'd run a query like

```
SELECT client->>'id' AS id, waist.planned
  FROM clients
 CROSS JOIN LATERAL JSONB_TO_RECORDSET(client->'waist') 
                 AS waist(planned TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE)
 WHERE waist.planned IS NOT NULL
```

but I need to get `waist.position_in_array` in some way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the function [`jsonb_array_elements(...)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) [`with ordinality.`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#queries-from)

```sql
select 
    client->>'id' as id, 
    (value->>'planned')::timestamptz as planned, 
    ordinality
from clients
cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(client->'waist') with ordinality
where value->>'planned' is not null;

      id      |         planned          | ordinality 
--------------+--------------------------+------------
 cj49q33oa000 | 2017-06-23 12:37:37.5+02 |          2
 cj49q33oa000 | 2017-06-23 12:37:37.5+02 |          3
 cj49q33oa000 | 2017-06-23 12:37:37.5+02 |          4
(4 rows)
```

[Db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=5a184a4ec52af3233908ea4598f50d86)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the ROWS FROM syntax to combine `json_to_recordset` and `jsonb_to_recordset` with `WITH ORDINALITY`.

The documentation as back as 9.5 says

> ROWS FROM( function_call [, ... ] ) [WITH ORDINALITY] [[AS] table_alias [(column_alias [, ... ])]]

So this works (tested on 12 but should work at least on all versions >=9.5)

```
WITH my_json AS 
(
  SELECT '[{"id":1, "name":"somename", "bool":true},
           {"id":2, "name":null, "bool":false}]'::json jsn
)
SELECT jsn_with_ordinality.*
  FROM my_json,
  ROWS FROM (json_to_recordset(jsn) AS (id int, name TEXT, bool boolean)) 
  WITH ORDINALITY jsn_with_ordinality;
```

Results in:

| id | name | bool | ordinality |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | somename | true | 1 |
| 2 |  | false | 2 |

I do wonder however if it's any safer than just adding a `row_number() over()...`

Comment: Thanks for good answer! For the last comment, can we achieve the same thing with row_number window function? row_number returns the order in the result set, not in the source data.
```select
  ordinality,
  item_id,
  sum(quantity) over (partition by item_id),
  row_number() over ()
from rows from (jsonb_to_recordset('[{"item_id":1,"quantity":1},{"item_id":2,"quantity":1},{"item_id":1,"quantity":1}]'::jsonb) as (item_id bigint, quantity numeric)) with ordinality t;```

Comment: @bongya I was curious too - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65109295/is-with-ordinality-on-table-functions-safer-than-row-number-over