# Is WITH ORDINALITY on table functions safer than row_number() over()

Tags: postgresql

UPDATE (TLDR;):

1. Prefer using `WITH ORDINALITY` over `row_number() over()`.
2. `WITH ORDINALITY` by itself is not related to guaranteeing the order of the rows returned from the table function itself.

---

Since I wasn't sure if `json(b)_to_recordset` is guaranteed to return the order as in the original json array, I searched for a version with `WITH ORDINALITY` and found this:

> ROWS FROM( function_call [, ... ] ) [WITH ORDINALITY] [[AS]
> table_alias [(column_alias [, ... ])]]

So this works (tested on 12 but should work at least on all versions >=9.5)

```
WITH my_json AS (
    SELECT '[{"id":1, "name":"somename", "bool":true},{"id":2, "name":null, "bool":false}]'::json jsn
)
SELECT jsn_with_ordinality.*
FROM my_json,
    ROWS FROM (json_to_recordset(jsn) AS (id int, name TEXT, bool boolean)) WITH ORDINALITY jsn_with_ordinality;
```

Results in:

```
id|name    |bool |ordinality|
--|--------|-----|----------|
 1|somename|true |         1|
 2|        |false|         2|
```

My question is - is this any safer (aka guarantees same order) than just adding `row_number() over()` (assuming no joins and other columns involved)?

My assumption is NO - in the `ROWS FROM` syntax the `WITH ORDINALITY` acts *after* the result from `json_to_recordset` is obtained, but I'm not 100% sure.

I know `WITH ORDINALITY` it is supported in `json_array_elements` and `unnest`, but they don't return a dynamic number of output fields which may explain why it's not natively supported with `json_to_recordset` (although I wish it would).

Thanks

Comment: `row_number() over()` essentially does not *guarantee* any order as you don't have an `order by`. So, yes using `with ordinality` would be safer.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'd assume not even `WITH ORDINALITY` guarantees any order unless you use `ORDER BY ordinal`?

Comment: I'm not certain why you assume that `json_to_recordset` does not ("natively") support `WITH ORDINALITY`?

Comment: @Bergi: but the index values generated by `with ordinality` will always reflect the position in the array. If you order the final result by that or not is a different topic

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name oh, I thought you were referring to the order of the final result, yes of course `row_number()` doesn't reflect the array position.

Comment: @Bergi because the `ROWS FROM` seems too generic and can be used with any table-returning function. If it did natively support it - I wouldn't need the `ROWS FROM` syntax and would use it directly like it works for `unnest`, wouldn't I?

Comment: @Pyrocks `json_to_recordset` *is* a table-returning function, exactly like [`unnest`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html), and like any of them they can be used with `ROWS FROM` or without. What's special about `json_to_recordset` is that it returns a record so you must give a column definition, and if you want to use that `WITH ORDINALITY` it requires you to use `ROWS FROM` syntax to disambiguate.

Comment: @Bergi I know that, and I have stated that in my question.
My initial concern was whether `json_to_recordset` guarantees to return the rows in the same order as they appear in the actual JSON. I assume unnest guarantees the order regardless of whether you use `WITH ORDINALITY` or not, but I take your point that `WITH ORDINALITY` has nothing to do with "guaranteeing" the order either way, not even for unnest.

Comment: "*I assume unnest guarantees the order*" - nothing _guarantees_ the order of rows unless you use `order by`. Any order in the result you see without an `order by` is pure coincidence and you can't rely on that. If you need a _guaranteed_ order you **have** to use `order by` And you can only do that if you get the real element index using `with ordinality`

Comment: @Pyrocks yes, `json_to_recordset` will emit the records in the order as they occur in the array, so that `with ordinality` will number them in that order.